# how to access log4net custom properties for AdoNetAppender?

Tags: properties, log4net

I am adding properties into

```
LogicalThreadContext.Properties["callContextId"] = "123456";
```

And my config looks like this:

```
<parameter>
  <parameterName value="@CallContextId" />
  <dbType value="String" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%property{callContextId}" />
  </layout>
</parameter>
```

This all works... but can I add a complex object and access its property? e.g.

```
myObject.Id = "123456";
LogicalThreadContext.Properties["callContext"] = myObject;
```

and I want to do something like this... is it at all supported/possible?

```
<conversionPattern value="%property{callContext}.Id" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't supported by log4net.

If you look at the code in [`PropertyPatternConverter`](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/logging/log4net/trunk/src/log4net/Util/PatternStringConverters/PropertyPatternConverter.cs), you see it calls `WriteObject` in the [`PatternConverter` class](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/logging/log4net/trunk/src/log4net/Util/PatternConverter.cs), which then just calls `ToString` on the object stored in the property.

It wouldn't be easy to implement either, as you would have to have code to extract the property name, then use reflection to extract the value. As you can accomplish the same thing by just storing the object property's value in the `LogicalThreadContext.Properties`, it isn't worthwhile.